# How to lock or set the seed in Linux?

Tags: linux, noita

Is it possible to lock or set the world seed in Noita on Linux, to replay it?

[image: Start screen with seed]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this script](https://github.com/Dregu/NoitaScripts/blob/master/SetSeed.ps1):

One-time setup:

1. Disable Steam Cloud synchronization, if enabled. Otherwise Steam seems to detect your shenanigans and reverts the files when starting the game.
2. Set the Noita launch options to `-magic_numbers magic.txt -no_logo_splashes`.
3. Create the seed file with the number you want:

   ```
   printf '<MagicNumbers WORLD_SEED="%s" />' 12345678 > "$(locate --regex '/steamapps/common/Noita$')/magic.txt"
   ```

Every time you want to run with a specific seed, remove the current save files and relaunch:

```
rm -r "$(locate --regex '/steamapps/compatdata/881100/pfx/drive_c/users/steamuser/AppData/LocalLow/Nolla_Games_Noita/save00$')/"{magic_numbers.salakieli,player.salakieli,world,world_state.salakieli}; steam steam://rungameid/881100
```